# Sending E-Mails via SMTP with email address that contains special characters

Tags: craft3, emails

I got a problem with some smtp settings in my craft 3.5.14. The domain of my client uses special characters like (ö, ä, ü) and therefore for their email addresses. In this case my client only use the character "ö". When using those email addresses for authentication I always get an error when testing it in craft (settings/email). I can't find anything in the logs. Is it generally possible to send emails with special characters in their domain? Something to watch out for? I also tried to convert the email address into ace through an idn converter. No success. When using another provider on another domain without special characters the sending of emails works. Thx for you help!

Comment: What special characters are you having issues with?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I updated my question accordingly. :)

Comment: Is the special character to the left or right of the @? i.e. `ö@site.com` or `me@söte.com`?

Comment: It is on the right side. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

After endless try and error I finally got it work. I used the ACE version of the email address e.g.

```
client@clientwithö.de -> client@xn--clientwith-ncb.de
```

Although I tried this at the beginning it is working now and I do not know what changed the result. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replying here because I am encountering a similar issue on an ecommerce site I am building. Craft version is 4.6.0 and I am not able to save the email address containing an umlaut in the domain as the system email or Commerce status email. Error is → `System Email Address is not a valid email address.`

Although converting the domain part of the email to punycode technically works as well, I would rather not do that and use the original address instead, i.e. *me@söte.de* since the ACE version of the email might look suspicious and less trustworthy to the untrained eye of a recipient.

So, is there a way to do use *me@söte.de* as system email, *Commerce* status update etc.?